# Hibernate don't close JDBC Connections

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jsf-2, jdbc

I have a JSF web application running on tomcat.
This application connect to Postgres database using hibernate.

After some time, the applications stops working because it can't open new connections.
If a execute the following sql in postgres:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity
```

It shows me 100 records, and in the column "state" it shows me idle.
I tracked down the statements that caused this, and found that executing one statement many times can cause the behavior (in my case, it was an autoComplete ajax method).
This is the statement:

```
Connection con = ConnectDb.getConnection();
    ArrayList<Cidade> cidades=new ArrayList<Cidade>();
    try{
        PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("select c.cidCodigo,c.cidNome,e.estCodigo,e.estSigla from cidade c left join estado e on e.estCodigo=c.estCodigo where upper(c.cidNome) like ?");
        pst.setObject(1, s.toUpperCase()+"%");
        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            Cidade c = new Cidade(rs.getInt("cidCodigo"), rs.getString("cidNome"));
            Estado e = new Estado();
            e.setEstCodigo(rs.getInt("estCodigo"));
            e.setEstSigla(rs.getString("estSigla"));
            c.setCidEstado(e);
            cidades.add(c);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        JsfUtils.showFatalMessage("Erro ao carregar dados: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            con.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is how I get the connections:

```
public class ConnectDb {

static EntityManagerFactory emf;

public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    return getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
}

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    if(emf==null){
        try {
            emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GestaoPU");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return emf;
}

public static Session getSession(){
    Session session = getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
    return session;
}

public static Connection getConnection(){
    Object delegate = getEntityManager().getDelegate();
    SessionImpl si=(SessionImpl)delegate;
    Connection con = si.connection();
    try {con.setAutoCommit(false);} catch (SQLException e) {}
    return con;
}
```

}

What can be causing this problem?

Comment: Maybe you need to keep a reference to the EntityManager and call close() on it. Just a guess.

Comment: I noticed the problem also happens when using Session/EntityManager, so i dont think this is the case...

Answer (score 0):

Connection.close() does not always physically "close" a connection. Typically in production code, a connection is wrapped in a proxy that is produced by a connection pool. The close method in the proxy may not close the connection, but instead returns it to the pool.

Since you have opened a ResultSet without closing it, you may have a resource leak.

Next, since you have "borrowed" the connection from hibernate, you should not explicitly return the connection to the pool (or close it behind hibernate's back so to speak).

Third, since you the only reference to the session that was returned from getDelegate() is in ConnectDb.getConnection(), it is somewhat unclear what happens to that session. This depends on the context from which it is called. It may be immediately eligible for garbage collection, or it may be held by a thread local. If it is in fact immediately gc'd then the hibernate session will return its connection to the pool before your code has had a chance to use it. This could result in unpredictable behavior or difficult to track down bugs.

Fourth, the prepared statement that you have created that is never closed may be another resource leak.

Comment: First, does not the closing of a Connection automatically closes its Statements and ResultSets?
Second, i never defined Connection Pool on the application, is there a "default" connection pool using hibernate?
Fourth, the same of First, does not the closure of the PreparedStatement auto closes the ResultSets associated to it?

Comment: The closing of a connection that belongs to a connection pool does not necessarily result in the closing of its statements and resultsets. It only returns the connection to the pool. This can be implementation dependent because the connection pool implementation may provide a proxy or connection that intrinsically tracks the resources that were created during the active cycle of the the connection, and therefore close those resources when the connection is returned to the pool.There is no implementation I am aware of that closes the resultsets generated by the statement when it is closed.

Comment: The author of this linked article provides some more insight into how to properly close jdbc resources. http://blog.shinetech.com/2007/08/04/how-to-close-jdbc-resources-properly-every-time/

In my opinion though, his exception handling is flawed as an exception out of any of the close statements will suppress any exceptions generated by the iteration and processing of the resultset.